# WSO2 API Manager: how is "import swagger definition" expected to be used?

Tags: api, wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

We have a service with ~200 API. The API are swagger enabled and accessible at http://localhost:8080/api-docs.

WSO2 AM provides an option to import the swagger definitions.

While importing should we specify the base api-docs URL (http://localhost:8080/api-docs)? In this case all API are imported under a single API (i.e., all 200 API appear under a single API in publisher). Is this the right way? Is there way to import each API separately?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager will treat as a single API when it imports a swagger file. If your swagger contains multiple API definitions, you may break it to pieces before importing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it doesnt make sense. We already have a service which exposes several API. These API will be in one swagger document. How can we split into multiple API? Swagger provides one endpoint per service. The only solution would be to split the API itself into separate services, which is major re-engineering work.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the whole group of 200 API definitions multiple times and drop the one you don't want in WSO2 API Manager UI. This way you will split  your big service in multiple WSO2 APIs without "major re-engineering" work.

For example you import your service twice, and you keep the first 100 API definitions in first WSO2 API and the 100 others in second WSO2 API.